# I am create a Report using Report Builder 3.0.This is my Expression . But only work when Measured Qty > 0.00 , when Measured Quantity 0.00 get #Error

Tags: reportbuilder3.0

=IIF(Fields!MeasuredQty.Value > 0.00, (Sum(Fields!Amount.Value) + ((Sum(Fields!Amount.Value)) * Fields!OverHead.Value/100))/Fields!MeasuredQty.Value, (Sum(Fields!Amount.Value) + (Sum(Fields!Amount.Value) * Fields!OverHead.Value/100)))

Comment: This has nothing to do with asp.net-mvc. Tag you question correctly.

Comment: Report Builder 3.0

Answer (score 0):

Got the right answer using following code :)

=IIF(Fields!MeasuredQty.Value = 0, (Sum(Fields!Amount.Value) + (Sum(Fields!Amount.Value)) *(Fields!OverHead.Value/100)) ,(Sum(Fields!Amount.Value) + (Sum(Fields!Amount.Value)) *(Fields!OverHead.Value/100))/IIF(Fields!MeasuredQty.Value=0,100,Fields!MeasuredQty.Value))